# How to embed music to one's Facebook wall using PHP SDK 3.0?

Tags: php, facebook, mp3, facebook-wall

I want to develop an application that posts mp3 files to people's walls (with an embedded music player). [Stream Attachments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/) look like the way to go but I can't really find a tutorial as to how to use these methods given the new PHP SDK.

Given that I need an inline mp3 player inside the user's wall, are Stream Attachments what I really need? If so, does anyone of you know how to implement it using FB's PHP SDK 3.0? If not, what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to make sense. It states in the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) to "use the Graph API and POST a Post object to the feed connection of the User object".

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) is information about the User object. You should be able to use the Source field to specify a Flash movie (serving as the MP3 player) as noted [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Comment: so it would seem that the new API does not support music attachments yet?